# Connecting to Sql Server Database with hyphenated name

Tags: sql-server, database, escaping, ado

I don't seem to be able to find a way to escape this hyphenated database name so that I can open a connection to it.  The database name is `EDMS-Lok` and my code looks like this (ADOcon is an ADO connection object):

```
strConBase="DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=LOKDB;UID=secret;PWD=secret;APP=LokENG_TESTS;WSID=LOKSPEC1;DATABASE=[EDMS-Lok];Network=DBMSSOCN;Trusted_Connection=NO;
ADOcon.ConnectionString = strConBase
ADOcon.Open"
```

I've tried the database name without enclosing brackets.  I've tried enclosing it in square brackets, curly brackets, parentheses, back-ticks, single quotes, double quotes, etc.  I've tried backslash and exclamation points.  I can't find a way to escape the database name so that I can connect to it.

The error message I get is:
`Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': 
[Microsoft][ODBS SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "[EDMS-Lok]" requested by the login.  The login failed.`

The database name and credentials are correct. I can access it if I omit the database name argument from the connection string, and then use the fully qualified name in my SQL statements (i.e. `SELECT * FROM [EDMS-Lok].dbo.tablename`)

However, I really don't want to do this, as I'm trying to use modular code that does the same actions on multiple databases. What I want is to open the connection to one database, run some SQL procedures, close the connection, then open a connection to another database and run the same SQL procedures.  Lather, rinse, repeat.

Also, before someone asks, I do not have the option of changing the database name.

As a test, I used the exact same connection string to connect to another database on the server that did not have a hyphenated name and it worked without error, so I'm pretty sure it's the stupid hyphenated name that is the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `Driver=SQL Server`? Try leaving that out or using SQLNCLI instead. (Or better yet, stop naming databases with troublesome characters.)

Comment: Hi Aaron, I'm using thE `SQL Server` driver because thats what I saw listed on connectionstrings.com for our server. I will try your suggestion as soon as I get back to the office.  Unfortunately I'm working with an existing database and don't have the option to change the name, gotta work with what someone else started.

Comment: Aaron, I tried both omitting the driver statement and using the SQL native client driver you suggested.  I get a "data source not found and no default driver specified" error when I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not get this to work the way I wanted to through an ODBC connection using the MSDASQL provider.

I ran some tests and I seem to be able to connect through OLE DB using the SQLOLEDB provider. So, I think I will just go back and modify the existing code to use an OLE DB connection.

Using OLE DB, I've found I can leave the database name un-escaped, i.e. `INITIAL CATALOG=EDMS-Lok;` or I can escape using double quotes, i.e. `INITIAL CATALOG="EDMS-Lok";`.  Square brackets however threw an error when I tried them, so for now I will stick to double quotes or un-escaped database names.

Thanks!